# Heap buffer overflow in Search a 2D Matrix on LeetCode

Tags: c++, 2d, buffer, heap-memory

I am coding a solution for LeetCode problem [74. Search a 2D Matrix](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix/):

> Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value in an `m x n` matrix. This matrix has the following properties:
>
> - Integers in each row are sorted from left to right.
> - The first integer of each row is greater than the last integer of the previous row.

Here is my code:

```
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
    int m=matrix.size()-1, n= matrix[0].size()-1;
    int i=0, j=n;
    int small=matrix[0][0], large=matrix[m][n];
    if(target<small || target>large)return false;
    
    while(i<=n && j>=0){
        if(target==matrix[i][j])return true;
        if(target<matrix[i][j])j--;
        else i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code is running fine for many cases, but it fails for this test case:

- Input:

  ```
  [[-1,3]]
  1
  ```
- Expected output: `false`

My output:

```
=================================================================
==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x603000000778 at pc 0x000000345efd bp 0x7ffc1c1fc3f0 sp 0x7ffc1c1fc3e8
READ of size 8 at 0x603000000778 thread T0
    #4 0x7fc2b36c60b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x603000000778 is located 0 bytes to the right of 24-byte region [0x603000000760,0x603000000778)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #6 0x7fc2b36c60b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff8090: fa fa fd fd fd fd fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd
  0x0c067fff80a0: fd fd fa fa fd fd fd fd fa fa fd fd fd fd fa fa
  0x0c067fff80b0: fd fd fd fd fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa
  0x0c067fff80c0: fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd
  0x0c067fff80d0: fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa
=>0x0c067fff80e0: fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa 00 00 00[fa]
  0x0c067fff80f0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8100: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8110: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8120: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8130: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==29==ABORTING
```

Which condition am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best optimal solution

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
        
        if(!matrix.size()){
            return false;
        }
        int n = matrix.length;
        int m = matrix[0].length;
        
        int a=0;
        int b = (n*m)-1;
        **// Binary Search** 
        while(a<=b){
            int c = (a+(b-a)/2);
            if(matrix[c/m][c%m] == target){
                return true;
            }
            if(matrix[c/m][c%m] <target){
                a = c+1;
            }
            else{
                b = c-1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you require `i <= n`, but `i` has nothing to do with `n`, but with `m`. In cases where `n > m`, you risk to perform an out-of-range access to `matrix[i]`, and the error message you had is the consequence of that.

So change `i <= n` to `i <= m`.